# How to choose where to save txt files in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to let user choose where to save txt file in my Android app using file explorer. Right now i'm saving it in the simplest way:

```
val fileName = "test.txt"
val fileBody = "test"

context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use { output ->
    output.write(fileBody.toByteArray())
}
```

But i want something like "Save as..." option like in this google docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file

Can you help me to do that?

Comment: You linked to the documentation for what you want to do. FWIW, [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v2.2/ContentEditor) demonstrates it.

Comment: @CommonsWare is that exactly what i want? like to choose specific place to save the txt file

Comment: `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` (or `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`) will allow the user to choose a location where to save the content. That may not be a "file", as the user might choose a cloud storage provider, but that is all handled for you by the framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you tell please where can i put text strings in my txt file if i will use this intent? Like we put file name as putExtra, but where can we put content of this file?

Comment: You get a `Uri` back from your request. You can pass that to `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `OutputStream` that you use to write out your content.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks. I have another question :) I guess it's not in this term but how can i use this with new activity launcher api? It's described with deprecated method. I mean how can i pass my Intent with setted MIME type etc by using `getContent.launch()` method?

Comment: "I guess it's not in this term but how can i use this with new activity launcher api?" -- that is `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`. The sample app that I linked to [uses it here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.2/ContentEditor/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/contenteditor/MainActivity.kt). Note, though, that it does not appear to take a MIME type.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks again :) so MIME type doesn't matter then? I'm just using CSV format, i'm afraid user can change file type so it will be "broken"

Comment: @CommonsWare files on Android kinda tricky tho :D

Comment: "so MIME type doesn't matter then?" -- to be honest, I was surprised that `CreateDocument` does not seem to provide an option for it. [`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT) says that it is required. The implementation of `CreateDocument` uses `*/*`. You could override `createIntent()` and call `setType()` on the `Intent` returned by `super.createIntent()` and try that.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you :)